# convert a select to an input not cross-browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, input, cross-browser

i have this markup

```
<select id="helpamount" name="helpamount"><?= get_texto_clave('amount')?>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="-1" class="convertoinput">more</option>
</select>
```

and this code to try to convert it to an input

```
$('body').on('click','.convertoinput',function(){
    $(this).parent().after('<input type="number" id="'+$(this).parent().attr('id')+'" name="'+$(this).parent().attr('id')+'" value="" placeholder="Especifica un valor numerico" /> ');
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Any idea why this is only working in firefox?

Comment: probably more reliable to bind to the change event of the select element and then check the selected value.

Comment: you're using `$(this).parent` way too many times, forcing jQuery to create an object from the select element and then find its parent... this is very wasteful and slow... just do `var e = $(this).parent;` and re-use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross browser ->

```
$('body').on('change','#helpamount',function(){
    if($(this).val() == -1){
        $(this).after('<input type="number" id="'+$(this).prop('id')+'" name="'+$(this).prop('id')+'" value="" placeholder="Especifica un valor numerico" /> ');
        $(this).remove();
    }
    $('body').off('change', '#helpamount');
});​
```

[jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/J4FEp/)

Comment: just please, don't be as wasteful with $(this) and all :D

Comment: @Toni Michel Caubet -- You can see it works fine in the jsFiddle example. What exactly 'fails'?

Comment: it seems that some weird char got copied.. :S, sorry, works great !

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
$('body').on('change','#helpamount',function(){
    var
        e = $(this),
        eid = e.attr('id');

    if (e.val() == e.find('option.convertoinput').val()) {
        e.after('<input type="number" id="'+eid+'" name="'+eid+'" value="" placeholder="Especifica un valor numerico" />').remove();
        $('body').off('change', '#helpamount');
    }
});​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zSbUA/1/

Comment: Also, this will cause several elements to be created when 'changing' the newly created inputs because their share the exact same ID, please see in my answer why I used the `.off()` method.

Comment: excellent remark, I didn't think of that... I'll delete this answer, but how about you update yours to re-use $(this) as a stored variable? :)